# Unpacking both list and dictionary into same parameter

Tags: python

```
def foo(l=None, d=None):
    return bar(*l, **d) # eg. bar(1, 2, 3, a=a, b=b)
```

Input:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
d = {'a': a, 'b': b}

foo(l=l, d=d)
```

Problem arises when `l` is `None`, ie. this call is made:

```
foo(d={'a':a})
```

What do I change in `foo` to handle `NoneType` on both the list and the dict nicely?

This is ugly, there has to be a better way than this:

```
def foo(l=None, d=None):
    if l is not None and d is not None:
        return bar(*l, **d)
    if l is not None:
        return bar(*l)
    if d is not None:
        return bar(**d)
```

Comment: The *better* way would be not to have a wrapper function `foo` that exposes just a list and a dictionary argument. If you have variable/keyword arguments, just expose that in the function signature, so users know they can use it.

Comment: `if l is not None and d is not None:` is ugly, use `if l and d:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can short-circuit with empty iterables using `or`:

```
def foo(l=None, d=None):
    return bar(*(l or ()), **(d or {}))
```

Or make it more readable, albeit more verbose with:

```
def foo(l=None, d=None):
    l = l or ()
    d = d or {}
    return bar(*l, **d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an empty tuple and an empty dictionary as default arguments instead of `None`:

```
def foo(l=(), d={}):
    return bar(*l, **d)
```

You have to be careful not to change `d` inside the `foo` function because it's a mutable default argument (see also ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)). If you want to be cautious you could use an [immutable dictionary](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.MappingProxyType):

```
from types import MappingProxyType  # requires python 3.3

def foo(l=(), d=MappingProxyType({})):
    return bar(*l, **d)
```

Comment: Why a tuple though? Why not an empty list for `l`?

Comment: Not sure about `d = {}`, since dicts are mutable.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye If the only purpose of the function is unpacking the dict then there's nothing that can change the dict.

Comment: Be very careful with such things though. it works here, since the list and dict are immediately unpacked, but it is very dangerous in general to have mutable defaults: [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/216074)

Comment: I select @MosesKoledoye's answer because as others have said, `{}` is mutable and so I prefer the `None` being default style.

Comment: That's your call. In your case it doesn't matter if it's mutable or not and even if it would matter just use an read-only dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check, Will this help you..

```
def bar(*mylist, **mydict):
    print mylist
    print mydict


def foo(arg=None, kwarg=None):
    if not isinstance(arg, list):
        arg = []
    if not isinstance(kwarg, dict):
        kwarg = {}
    return bar(*arg, **kwarg)


l = [1, 2, 3]
d  ={'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}

foo(l,d)
foo(l, None)
foo(None,d)
```

output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}

(1, 2, 3)
{}

()
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
```